# Wrong datetime format on ASP.NET Core application

Tags: datetime, asp.net-core, format, culture

I would like to set the same datetime format (pl-PL) on ASP.NET Core application. I use pl-PL culture in my configuration:

```
        services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
        {
            var supportedCultures = new[]
            {
                new CultureInfo("pl-PL"),
            };
            options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("pl-PL", "pl-PL");
            options.DefaultRequestCulture.Culture.DateTimeFormat.FullDateTimePattern = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss";
            options.DefaultRequestCulture.Culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd.MM.yyyy";
            options.DefaultRequestCulture.UICulture.DateTimeFormat.FullDateTimePattern = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss";
            options.DefaultRequestCulture.UICulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd.MM.yyyy";
            

            options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
            options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;

        });
```

It is not enough. I still had problems with binding dates, eg. 01.02.2013 was binding as 02.01.2013.
Therefore I wrote custom binder:

```
public class DateTimeModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));

        // Try to fetch the value of the argument by name
        var modelName = bindingContext.ModelName;
        var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(modelName);
        if (valueProviderResult == ValueProviderResult.None)
            return Task.CompletedTask;

        bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(modelName, valueProviderResult);

        var dateStr = valueProviderResult.FirstValue;
        // Here you define your custom parsing logic, i.e. using "pl-PL" culture

        
        if (!DateTime.TryParse(dateStr, new CultureInfo("pl-PL"), DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
        {
              bindingContext.ModelState.TryAddModelError(bindingContext.ModelName, "Data powinna być w formacie 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss'");
              return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
            

        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(date);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

It started working, but just locally (on the computer with polish operating system). I figure it out that Culture('pl-PL') must be different on the production server (but i dont know why). So, I decided to add:

```
if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(dateStr, "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime date))
            {
                if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(dateStr, "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
                {
                    if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(dateStr, "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
                    {
                        if (!DateTime.TryParse(dateStr, new CultureInfo("pl-PL"), DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
                        {
                            bindingContext.ModelState.TryAddModelError(bindingContext.ModelName, "Data powinna być w formacie 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss'");
                            return Task.CompletedTask;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

This solution works but its ugly.
What is also important, I noticed that data format looks different between different browsers.
On the Firefox: Od: 19.02.2021 Do: 05.03.2021 (correct)
On the Chrome: Od: 2021-02-19 Do: 2021-03-05 (wrong)

Code which returns dates on presentation layer:

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
Od: @vehicleAvailability.DateFrom.ToShortDateString()
Do: @vehicleAvailability.DateTo.ToShortDateString()
</div>
```

Comment: "Culture('pl-PL') must be different on the production server" - what does this even mean? And how do you make request to api? From `form` or using javascript? And can you add api code which return data to display for this *On the Firefox: Od: 19.02.2021 Do: 05.03.2021 (correct) On the Chrome: Od: 2021-02-19 Do: 2021-03-05 (wrong)*

Comment: @Alexander via form. I know that sounds funny. I Added logging to check error on production server:
dateStr before parsing and date.ToString() after parsing.
dateString equals 01.02.2013 but after parsing date is wrong.

Comment: @Alexander I added code which displays dates to the post.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between Chrome and Firefox in your case that they are sending different `Accept-Language` headers, you can check it in network tab. If you want to display specific date format consider specifying culture in `DateTime.ToString`

```
<!-- ToShortDateString() equals ToString("d") -->
<div class="col-sm-3">
Od: @vehicleAvailability.DateFrom.ToString("d", new CultureInfo("pl-PL")) 
Do: @vehicleAvailability.DateTo.ToString("d", new CultureInfo("pl-PL"))
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to turn it globally? I would like to set the same culture for the all places in application.

Comment: @marmite Actually the code you have posted restricts application to single supported cultrue which is `pl-PL` so you couldn't really have different results with different browser with this settings. Do you have extra code for localization? Anything else in `UseRequestLocalization`?

Comment: you were right! I removed "app.UseRequestLocalization();" and it helped with displaing. But i still had problem with binding :/